# Odoo - Internal server error after installation custom module

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i tried to make a calculation module in odoo but internal server error after i install the module and i don't know it. I just learned odoo and i hope for your help.

hit.py

```
from openerp import osv, fields
class hit(osv.osv):
_name       = 'eha.hit'
_columns    = {
    'num1'      : fields.float('Number 1'),
    'num2'      : fields.float('Number 2')
}

def on_change_price(self,cr,user,ids,num1,num2,context=None):
#Calculate the total
total = num1 + num2
    res = {
        'value': {
    #This sets the total price on the field standard_price.
            'standard_price': total
      }
}
#Return the values to update it in the view.
return res
```

hit.xml:

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="hitung_list" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">pajak_list</field>
        <field name="model">eha.hit</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='standard_price']" position="before">
                <field name ="num1" on_change="on_change_price(num1,num2)"/>
                <field name ="num2" on_change="on_change_price(num1,num2)" />
                </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
    </data>
   </openerp>
```

after i install the module i got "internal server odoo"

```
File "E:\Odoo 8.0-20160615\server\openerp\addons\pajak\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
import pph
File "E:\Odoo 8.0-20160615\server\openerp\addons\pajak\pph.py", line 6
results = {}
           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) usually happens before you have an exception on the server side. Try to take a look to the logs to get more info on what the exception is, and add that info to your question. Also, try to avoid images please, the image you posted could be just a copy-paste of the text. Thanks.

Comment: It's an error on the server side...you'll have to show us the exact error message you are getting from your logs or from the terminal (if you didn't save the logs to a file). but from your `hit.xml` file i can see that you try to use xpath but you never inherit from any previous template.....that's definitely going to throw an error because there is no field name called `standard price`

Answer (score 0):

After `class` , it should be intented

`class hit(osv.osv):`

```
   _name       = 'eha.hit'
```

Comment: Just a heads up, it's indented, not intended.

Comment: Oh Sorry @K3v1n.